# Multi-secret sharing (Packed secret sharing) - Some questions

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

In the publication - "[Communication complexity of secure computation](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=129780)", I have encountered a small problem - on page 5 of the literature under the heading "Theorem 1" they have described a $(c,d; k,n)$ multi-party secret sharing scheme.

Here, $d$ denotes the minimum number of parties that must come together to recover the secret, $k$ denotes the number of secrets, $n$ denotes the number of parties and $c$ denotes the maximum number of parties who together cannot gain any further information about the secret by collaborating.

I quote the text when it describes a $(t - k + 1, t + 1, k , n)$ multi-secret sharing scheme - (note $k \leq t< n$).

> Theorem 1: There is a $(t– k+ l,t + 1; k,n)$- multi-secret sharing
> scheme to share $k$ elements of a finite field $\mathbb{F}$ among $n$
> players, with $k < n,$ where each multi-share is a single element of F.
>
> **Proof:** Let $S_1, \ldots,S_k$ be the Dealer’s secrets. Assume that
> $a_l,....,a_k$ and $e_l,....,e_k$ are pre-selected elements
> of $\mathbb{F}$ that are known to the Dealer and all $n$ players.
>
> A generalization of
> Shamir’s secret-sharing scheme suffices. In the Distribution Phase,
> each player $i$ receives the multi-share $p(a_i),$ where $p(x) \in F[x]$
> is an otherwise random degree $t$ polynomial such that
> $$p(e_i) = S_i, 1 \leq i \leq k.$$
> More specifically, $$p(x) = q(x) \prod_{i = 1}^{k}(x – e_i) + \sum_{i = 1}^{k}S_i L_i(x),$$ where $q(x)$ is
> a completely random degree $t – k$ polynomial, and where $L_i(x)$ is the
> Lagrange polynomial.

**i. I seem to only see the $k$ multi-shares distributed to k out of n parties. Is this understanding of mine incorrect? What is the role of the other $(n-k)$ parties?**

ii. Are there any further resources online that I could refer to for such multi-secret sharing schemes? (preferably not academic literature as I'd like to work through some examples.)

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Write the question more clearly please, defining the symbols you use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback - I've tried to improve the same - do let me know if this is more sensible and clear than before!

Comment: You might need to quote a bit more context. Without reading the (paywalled) paper, I can't really tell what the other parties might be doing. It could even be that the $1 \le i \le k$ is just a typo, and it should read $1 \le i \le n$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that - just realized that I have access to it because of my university account - I have updated the same to include some more text!

Comment: Editing the question for more readability, with LaTeX, just use $ $ outside the expressions for proper typesetting.

Comment: I have been reading this paper recently and these questions bothered me, too. Did you figure them out? Maybe we could share some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a typo in the paper: instead of $k$ elements $a_1, \dots, a_k$ there should actually be $n$ fixed public elements, i.e. $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb F$. To secret-share, first determine $p(x)$ based on the dealer's secrets. Then, give $p(a_i)$ to player $i$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for this! I was a bit unsure if this is a mistake!

Answer (score 1):

From your quote, I get that ALL participants receive $p(a_i)$ where $p$ itself depends on the $k$ multishares. Therefore, ALL participants receive some information.

Somehow the information on the multishares is "spread-out" by the polynomial.